# Move google console project to another email id

Tags: google-console-developer

I want to move a google console project in my email id to a new email id.
Is that posssible?
I don't want to destruct the existing API keys by recreating the existing ones.
I just need to transfer whole google console project to another email id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to transfer Cloud Platform account access to another email address, you need to add your other email address as a `Project Owner[1]` and `Billing Administrator[2]`. Once added, it will send an invitation email to join the project and be a billing administrator of billing account. Once accepted, it will have project access at a resource level and billing privilege. In this way, other email address will also have an access to current Cloud Platform account.
If you wish that your other email address  will have sole access to the project and billing account, you may delete your current email address as a project owner same as being a billing administrator.